# Storing Files in a different Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it a good idea to store files in a different SQL Server 2005 database "FileDb" and point to it (files) in the "AppDb" by "FileId".

Please take in consideration that I have a dedicated server and I can create as many Sql Databases as I want.

## update:

Which perform better single database or multiple databsae?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filegroups](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1112) to separate your data files. You can create one separate filegroup for storing the file data.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to have a column which stores the file path + filename
I never liked the idea of storing it in the database because of the following reason:

bloats the database...backup and restore will take longer

image and text datatype is a pain in the neck to work with

In SQL Server 2008 you can use FILESTREAM which is still transactional but stores it as a file

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use table partitioning to have your file table on a different disk partition, or even server for performance reasons, but still have the table in one database.

- [SQL Server 2005 Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://www.sqlskills.com/resources/Whitepapers/Partitioning%20in%20SQL%20Server%202005%20Beta%20II.htm)
- [Database Table Partitioning Tutorial](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/)
- [Performance and scalability of table and index partitioning for use with very large tables](http://www.sqljunkies.com/article/f4920050-6c63-4109-93ff-c2b7eb0a5835.scuk)

Answer (score 0):

It can be extremely useful if you want to have different back up strategies for different sets of data.

Say for instance, you only need to back up files/emails/attachments every week, while the App data needs to be backed up daily.

This allows you to do that with ease.

I would highly recommend putting anything you would consider having different persistent strategies for on a different database.